# Checking continuity of a functional

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $p \in \mathbb{C}[x]$ and $\mathbb{C}[x]$ is endowed with the norm $\|p\| = sup \{|p(t)|:  t \in [0,1]\}$. I need to check if the functional $f(p) = p'(0)$ is continuous or not. I tend to think it's not. To prove it I tried to find some sequence in the unit ball which goes to unbounded set but I couldn't. I used the most simple ones like $2^{-n}(x+1)^n$ but it's image is bounded. What else can I do?

Comment: By Weiestrass' theorem there is a sequence of polynomials converging uniformly to $\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: @treeleaf, if it is not continuous, we don't know how to extend it, so we don't know how our functional acts on $\sqrt{x}$ which gives us nothing.

Comment: The functional doesn't need to act on $\sqrt{x}$ it acts on the sequence of polynomials.

Comment: @ treeleaf, okay, but how does it help? If we don't know how it acts on $\sqrt{x}$ we don't know that the sequence is unbounded, do we?

Comment: Sit on it for a while.

Comment: @Vladislav: the functional $f$ has the domain $ \mathbb C[x]$. The function $h(x):= \sqrt{x}$ is not in the domain of $f$. Hence you can not use $h$ in the investigation of the continuity of$f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try $p_n(x)=(x-1)^n$. Then $||p_n||=1$ and $|f(p_n)|=|p_n'(0)|=n=n ||p_n||$